# Leveled List to JSON (JAVA)

Tags: java, json, dictionary, data-structures, dataset

I'm working with an API that retrievies data from a level structure dataset.
In the WebSite it shows a Json structure like this:

```
- Item1
    - Item2
    - Item3
        - Item4
    - Item5
- Item6
    - Item7
        - Item8
            - Item9
...
```

The problem is that when I retrieve the data from the API, it comes in a txt file with each element displayed in lines like this (I think that is because they are working with SQL):

```
id:"1", Level:"1", name: "Item1"
id:"2", Level:"2", name: "Item2"
id:"3", Level:"2", name: "Item3"
id:"4", Level:"3", name: "Item4"
id:"5", Level:"2", name: "Item5"
id:"6", Level:"1", name: "Item6"
id:"7", Level:"2", name: "Item7"
id:"8", Level:"3", name: "Item8"
id:"9", Level:"4", name: "Item9"
...
```

Right now I'm converting each line to an object and storing all of them in a Map, with the id as a key. But I'd like to convert this to a JSON to make it easier to see and program the level structure. The problem is that I can't know for sure how many levels there will be and how many elements there will be in each level. Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Create a tree, fill items in the tree according to their level, print the tree. What do you have so far?

Comment: Also you're missing information here. How can you tell if `Item4` is a child of `Item3` and not a child of `Item2` ?  Or `Item8` is a child of `Item7` but not of `Item2` and `Item3` (which are also level 2 elements? )

Answer (score 1):

#### Logic

- Iterate all the elements
- Figure out the list where they belong to
- Add them to that list
- Mark the node as the list for the next level
- Repeat

#### Details

To keep track of the list where a node will go, you can create a map `level -> list`

```
var map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Node>>();
```

Then get the list for the current level and add the node

```
var list = map.get(node.level());
list.add(node);
```

Finally, and the most important part, add that node's list as the list where the next level will go

So, then you add `item1`, all the nodes with level 2 will go in its list.

When you add `item6` (which is also level 1) you will be replacing the place where level 2 go now (e.g. `item7`)

```
map.put(node.level() + 1, node.list());
```

So, putting all together it looks like this:

```java
    var map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Node>>();
    map.put(1, new ArrayList<>());
    for (var node: input) {
      var list = map.get(node.level());
      list.add(node);
      map.put(node.level() + 1, node.list());
    }
```

#### Standalone Example

```
import java.util.*;


class Main {

  public static void main(String ... args) {
    var input = Arrays.asList(
          node("1", "1",  "Item1"),
          node("2", "2",  "Item2"),
          node("3", "2",  "Item3"),
          node("4", "3",  "Item4"),
          node("5", "2",  "Item5"),
          node("6", "1",  "Item6"),
          node("7", "2",  "Item7"),
          node("8", "3",  "Item8"),
          node("9", "4",  "Item9")
    );
    var map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Node>>();
    map.put(1, new ArrayList<>()); // for top level
    for (var node: input) {
      var list = map.get(node.level());
      list.add(node);
      map.put(node.level() + 1, node.list());
    }
    System.out.println(map.get(1)); 
  }
  static record Node(String id, int level, String name, List<Node> list){}
  static Node node(String id, String level, String name) {
    return new Node(id, Integer.valueOf(level), name, new ArrayList<>());
  }

}
```

Output:

```
[
  Node[id=1, level=1, name=Item1, list=[
    Node[id=2, level=2, name=Item2, list=[]],
    Node[id=3, level=2, name=Item3, list=[
      Node[id=4, level=3, name=Item4, list=[]]
    ]],
    Node[id=5, level=2, name=Item5, list=[]]]
  ],
  Node[id=6, level=1, name=Item6, list=[
    Node[id=7, level=2, name=Item7, list=[
      Node[id=8, level=3, name=Item8, list=[
        Node[id=9, level=4, name=Item9, list=[]]
      ]]
    ]]
  ]]
]
```

From there you can walk the elements and transform it to JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much Oscar, I was trying to do this, but I wasted a long time and made a really inefficient algorithim. I should have posted what I had, but anyways, you helped me a lot !

Comment: @CesarLopes hah no problem, I was initially thinking "Oh that's easy just to this and that.." gave it a try and realized it was way harder than what I thought so I took it as a good exercise.

Comment: My txt has 300k rows. My code took 10mn to do all, basically I was using for inside for hahahhaa... With your method, took around 5mn.

Comment: 5 minutes for 300k rows? That's still a lot